# Magento setPrice is not work with catalog_block_product_list_collection event?

Tags: event-observer

This is my config code.

```
<catalog_block_product_list_collection>
            <observers>
                <smashingmagazine_logproductupdate>
                    <class>smashingmagazine_logproductupdate/observer</class>
                    <method>listingchange</method>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                </smashingmagazine_logproductupdate>
            </observers>
        </catalog_block_product_list_collection>
```

This is my function.

```
public function listingchange(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();

    foreach ($collection as $product)
    {
       $product->setPrice( 1500 );
    }

}
```

price get in list.phtml file price code is.

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
```

The setPrice() is not work. getPrice() function is work fine.

but setPrice() is not work.

please help. thank's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$product->setFinalPrice(1500);` if you want to set price immediately. If you change only price using `setPrice()`, than magento will calculate price via its own logic, see `Mage_catalog_Model_Product`:

```
public function getFinalPrice($qty=null)
    {
        $price = $this->_getData('final_price');
        if ($price !== null) {
            return $price;
        }
        return $this->getPriceModel()->getFinalPrice($qty, $this);
    }
```

Comment: hey this is working but the original price is set as 'As low as : $45' below price. please help.

Comment: This will be a long history, try to understand Magento product price calculation process

Comment: hey how can i changed price on cart view page please help.

Answer (score 1):

ISSUE WITH  you observer code

Try this

```
public function listingchange(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();


        foreach ($collection->getItems() as $_item ) {
                    $_item->setPrice( 1500 );
        }

        return $this;

}
```

Comment: This is not working.